# Update Elements in Array

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have this Object:

```
{town_id: 13, houses_data: [
    {house_id: 5, price: 32, description: "thats a house"},
    {house_id: 2, price: 12, description: "thats a house"}
   ]
 }
```

**And I want to update the desription of house with id 5 to "sold":**

```
{town_id: 13, houses_data: [
    {house_id: 5, price: 32, description: "sold"},
    {house_id: 2, price: 12, description: "thats a house"}
   ]
 }
```

**What I tried:**

```
 town1 = town.findOne({town_id: 13});
```

Get the houses_data:

```
 twon1.houses_data
```

And tried to update only the `house_data` where `id = 5`

```
 twon1.houses_data.find({house_id: 5}).update(description: "sold");
```

**But I get this error message:**

```
 [object Object],[object Object] has no method 'find'
```

What do I wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update the first embedded document matching the given query:

```
db.test.town.update({town_id: 13, "houses_data.house_id":5},
                    {$set: { "houses_data.$.description": "sold"}})
```